# What is the verb expressing that a child just wants their mom to be exclusively for them?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Now, a woman has a 5-year-old daughter and now she has just had a newborn baby. The daughter starts to get jealous of the baby because she just wants her mom to take care of her only not the baby.

**What is the verb expressing that a child just wants their mom to be exclusively for them?**

For example,

The daughter just wants to keep her mom to herself

The daughter just doesn't want to share her mom with the baby

Comment: I don't know a verb for it, but the feeling is described as _sibling jealousy_ or _sibling rivalry_ (though the second can also refer to ill-feeling between older siblings).

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possessive pretty well nails it.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence with a blank where you want the verb to go? Verbs typically represent actions not feelings/emotions, although there are many ways they can do the latter. I'm not sure there's a verb with the precise meaning, and it would probably normally be expressed in another way, but you should try and give us as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The verb is **possess** - to have and hold as property : own. The daughter is **possessive**.

Comment: But you can share possessions.

Comment: [Possessive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possessive) definitely has this meaning, but not sure possess does.